# SP.ClientContext.Load suddenly throwing uncaught TypeError?

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, jsom

I am trying to start a workflow from JSOM.  I just had it working fine, and then I had to change some of the other code in the JavaScript file that is *unrelated to the client context or executing queries*, and now when I try `context.load(clientObject)`, I get

> Uncaught TypeError: a.get_$y_0 is not a function

from SP.Runtime.js.

I can see that SP.js, SP.Core.js, SP.Runtime.js and SP.WorkflowServices.js are all loaded.

Here's my code:

```
MyNamespace.getWfSubscriptions = function () {
    var listID = _spPageContextInfo.pageListId;
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getById(listID);

    MyNamespace.wfServicesManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(context, web);
    context.load(MyNamespace.wfServicesManager);
    // I get the error right here, at the first context.load()

    MyNamespace.wfSubscriptions = MyNamespace.wfServicesManager.getWorkflowSubscriptionService().enumerateSubscriptionsByList(new SP.Guid(listID));
    context.load(MyNamespace.wfSubscriptions);
    context.executeQueryAsync(MyNamespace.startWorkflow, MyNamespace.showErrorNotification);
}
```

Again, this function is untouched from when it was working just earlier today.

Anyone have any idea as to what is going wrong here or what I might be missing?